# wamp - www directory doesnt open new document root

Tags: apache, wamp

I have changed default c:/wamp/www/ path to new directory c:/projectfolder/www/ in http.conf

The change has reflected, however when I click on the www directory in the wamp system tray (in windows 7), its still opening the old location c:/wamp/www/

I have restarted the service and exited wamp and relaunched and also rebooted the system but it still opens the old location.

Is this path taken from wamp settings somewhere instead of httpd.conf?

Note: Its not an issue for me except that I have to create a shortcut in explorer but I am running with another issue with flex, which I am not sure is anyway related to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the following part in the file C:\wamp\wampmanager.ini

```
[Menu.Left]
Type: item; Caption: "www directory"; Action: shellexecute; FileName: "c:/projectfolder/www/"; Glyph: 2
```

Here change the FileName to your new folder

Also change the following line in  C:\wamp\scripts\config.inc.php

```
$wwwDir = 'c:/projectfolder/www';//To ur new project directory
```

Comment: I was about to add comment and close :P. Thanks

Comment: Hey Akhil, it seems like wamp is restoring the old configuration. every time i relaunch the wamp, it changes the configuration file. I changed the file after closing the wamp, saved and relaunched wamp, but it still the same old directory. my folder name is around 60 chars wide, I hope it not an issue

Comment: @dev2dev pls check the edit , seems this will solve ur problem

Comment: The C:\wamp\scripts\config.inc.php is overwriting the c:\wamp\wampmanager.ini. so we should always change the php file not ini :) Thanks. I hope you agree with my edit in your post

Comment: @dev2dev Yeah sure , you may be rite as i have not tried this

Comment: Yes Akhil, it works, I tested with the change and without the change. I am not sure about remaining conf but its definitly chaning the [Menu.Left] entry

Comment: as @SolowDeveloper says, the ini file is recreated every time that wamp starts. Still working in wamp 3

Answer (score 0):

If WAMP has default installation then you need to make changes into following file to change the directory of "www"

go to `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf`

```
Open httpd.conf file
```

Search for

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
```

replace this line with your new directory

```
e.g DocumentRoot "d:/Sites/www/"
```

Then search for `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">`

and replace with `<Directory "d:/Sites/www/s">`

Hope it will helps ..

Answer (score 0):

Just as I had tried everything (including all the suggestions above and uninstalling and starting with a clean install), I was about to call the Exorcist. That's when it dawned on me that Virtual Hosts might be interfering with how URLs are mapped to files (a far fetch obviously, but all other possibilities had been exhausted).
Anyway, long story short, commenting out this line towards the bottom of **httpd.conf** did the magic for me.

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I am not sure how this gotcha could be happening only to me. Alternatively, I don't get why this is not more prominently documented, since I expect that many, like me, are installing WAMP to have a quick LAMP environment on their windows machine. Wampserver 3.0.4 here...